# Replace numbers below threshold in numpy array with zeros

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a `NxT` Numpy array in which I stored `N` time series (random walk) of length `T`.
I'm trying to replace all values of a given series (row) below a threshold, say 8000, with zeros. If a value in `t` is below the threshold all subsequent values will be zero regardless whether the random walk will climb above the threshold at some time later.

Comment: Please repeat [On topic]( https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask]( https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question]( https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)  from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  We expect you to present your coding attempt.  A generic "help me solve this problem" is off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Your array is `arr`. This is what you need:

```
arr[arr<8000] = 0
```

Or this if values increase after it hits lower than threshold:

```
idx = np.where(arr<8000)
indexer = idx[1][np.insert(np.diff(idx[0]),0,1)==1]
for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
  arr[i,indexer[i]:]=0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for. I don't think there is a vectorized solution for this that avoids explicit looping over the rows.

```
np.random.seed(2)
a = np.random.randint(10, size=(5, 10))
print(f'Original a:\n{a}')
for row in a:
    row[np.argwhere(row <= 2)[0, 0]:] = 0
    
print(f'Modified a:\n{a}')
```

Output:

```
Original a:
[[8 8 6 2 8 7 2 1 5 4]
 [4 5 7 3 6 4 3 7 6 1]
 [3 5 8 4 6 3 9 2 0 4]
 [2 4 1 7 8 2 9 8 7 1]
 [6 8 5 9 9 9 3 0 0 2]]
Modified a:
[[8 8 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [4 5 7 3 6 4 3 7 6 0]
 [3 5 8 4 6 3 9 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [6 8 5 9 9 9 3 0 0 0]]
```